# error message for missing argument, discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py, arguments

I'm very new to coding and am currently working on a discord bot, I would like to make it so that If the kick command is missing the member arg the bot will reply with 'user not found.' The code below is currently in a cog.

```
@commands.command()
@commands.has_permissions(kick_members=True)
async def kick(self, ctx, member: discord.Member, *, reason=None):
    await member.kick(reason=reason)
    await ctx.send(f'user {member} was kicked reason: "{reason}"')
```

Comment: Please post the full Error message.

Answer (score 0):

What you could do is add a `on_command_error` event. For the user not found error, you could use:

```py
@commands.event
async def on_command_error(ctx,error):
   elif isinstance(error,commands.UserNotFound):
        await ctx.send("**Error:** User not found  ")
   else:
        raise error
```

Comment: I'm getting in invalid syntax error, but thank you for replying